# LinearLayout covering entire screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, libgdx, admob, android-linearlayout

I recently made a game with LibGDX, and I added a `LinearLayout` in the `MainActivity.java` so that I could place an AdMob ad there. Everything is running fine and dandy, but the problem is the layout covers the entire screen with black, and I'm not able to load or play the game. Is there a way to make the LinearLayout right at the top of the screen (where most ads are), and have it exist there while allowing the game to loaded and be played? Because right now my app is just a black screen with an ad at the top.

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {

    AdView adView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;

        initialize(new MyGame(), cfg);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("My Ad Unit ID");

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        if (layout ==null)
            System.out.println("layout doesn't work");
        if (layout !=null)
            System.out.println("layout works");
        if (adView == null)
            System.out.println("adView doesn't work");   
        if (adView != null)
            System.out.println("adView works");


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("My Device ID")
        .build();

        if (adRequest == null)
            System.out.println("adRequest doesn't work");
        if (adRequest != null)
            System.out.println("adRequest works");


        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        setContentView(layout);
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
          }
          super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Here's the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use a specified dp value rather than `fill_parent` for `layout_height`

Comment: Try changing the `layout_height` parameter in your `main.xml` from `"fill_parent"` to `"wrap_content"` or even something like `"64dp"`.  To ensure this is at the top of the screen, you probably want to add it to an enclosing `RelativeLayout`, but that may not be necessary given what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

For linear layout you have given :

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This is causing it to fill the entire screen. You can try this :

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You can also specify specific height using some dp value for height or width

Comment: I tried adding `wrap_content`, and I think it's working, but the problem is that I think the LinearLayout is overwriting the line of code `initialize(new MyGame(), cfg);`. Because I put a `System.out.println("started");` to test for whenever the game starts, and it isn't starting. Is there a way to run my game, and the LinearLayout concurrently, with the game under the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that libGDX AndroidApplication#initialize (which you call in #onCreate) calls setContentView and then you replace that **twice**. #setContentView should only be called once with the layout for your Activity.